# Why might I see the following in the DOM of a web application?

Tags: html, dom

I see twenty or so instances of the following string in the DOM of a web application (https://state.com):

```
<!--`´-->
```

Why might this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code causing it is:

```
[var ...,] l = document.createComment("`\u00b4"),
    p = document.createComment("`\u00b4"),
    m = document.createDocumentFragment();
m.appendChild(l);
m.appendChild(i.domTree);
m.appendChild(p);
e.place(m, d[b], b);
```

While I couldn't possibly tell you *why* those comments are created and placed, this is the code that creates them. They appear to serve no purpose, other than maybe as debugging for the developer to go "okay, this element has been surrounded with `` <!--`´--> ``, that means it has been processed.

Comment: Interesting. I thought they might be an artefact of a client-side framework (similar to the extraneous divs often present in Backbone.js applications).

Answer (score -1):

It used to be used to attempt to hide JavaScript from non-compatible browsers I believe -- see http://www.plexoft.com/SBF/hideJS.html